# UE4 how to check a pointer if it's not initialized? C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

If i create a pointer and want to check it without get a error, how can i? Some methods are :

```
Ainfantry_actor* test_pointer;

if (IsValid(test_pointer)) { ... }
if (test_pointer!= nullptr) { ... }
if (test_pointer) { ... }
```

When i use one of these, get this : "uninitialized local variable 'test_pointer' "

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. The compiler can make a good guess, but even if it's right, that information isn't available to your program.

Comment: The contents of an uninitialized variable are **indeterminate**, so any test you might apply to its value could always succeed entirely by chance.  Therefore this is impossible. Indeed most such tests will cause undefined behavior anyway.  So come up with a better algorithm that doesn't involve this.

Comment: You could use `Ainfantry_actor* test_pointer = nullptr;`. Because you did not initialize the variable it gets a "random" value (if you use the debugger in visual-studio `test_pointer` would have the value `0xcccccccc`).

Comment: @Sebphil advice acceptable for me, thanks.

Comment: Reading uninitialized memory in any way is ub in c++. To answer your question at an unreal level, using IsValid will probably trip you up at some point. Using either `test_pointer!= nullptr` or simply `test_pointer` is enough to test whether a pointer is nullptr or not. You take this further with uobjects and also test if they're pending kill. However it's incredibly rare that's necessary, and when it is you'll probably be using weakptrs with that functionality built in.

Answer (score 1):

> how to check a pointer if it's not initialized? C++

There is no way to check whether an object is initialised.

There is also no way to check whether a pointer is valid.

There are ways to check whether a pointer has been initialised to null, and to check whether it points to a particular object. If you perform such checks on a pointer that isn't initialised, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here is a use of uninitialized variable and it is not only limited to pointers. Typically compilers will throw warnings when you declare variable and not initialize it. You should not have any uninitialized variables in your code.

Comment: "You should not have any uninitialized variables in your code." Is only mostly true. There's nothing wrong with allocating initialized memory. The issue comes when trying to read it before initializing (it's no accident that neither c or c++ zero initialise all memory).